# How to check if the directory is symlink in chef

Tags: shell, chef-infra

I just want to do delete directory if it is not symlnik.

```
directory "/var/www/html/" do
  action :delete
  only_if ???
end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The selected answer will not work on Windows or systems where Bash is the default interpreter. You should use a Ruby solution to be cross-platform (and faster, since there's no process spawning):

```rb
directory '/var/www/html' do
  action :delete
  not_if { File.symlink?('/var/www/html') }
end
```

Comment: Thank you! It sounds good. I changed the recipe and it works nice! Cookbook needs to be cross-platform. I changed the answer selection to yours.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
directory "/var/www/html/" do
    action :delete
    not_if "test -L /var/www/html/"
end
```

`test -L $file` returns 0 (true) if `$file` is a symlink.

Comment: Thanks! I solved the problem with your solution. But I eliminate last slash of paths.

Comment: I would go for a ruby-based solution in the `not_if` block. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897568/ruby-on-rails-check-if-a-directory-file-symlink-exists-with-one-command).

Comment: Thank you. ruby-based solution is better.