# Chef - Dir.exists? guard treating symlink as directory

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a recipe which deletes an empty logs directory, then replaces it with a symlink in the next step.

```
directory "#{ENV['GS_HOME']}/logs/" do
  action :delete
  only_if { ::Dir.exists?("#{ENV['GS_HOME']}/logs/") }
end
```

It works the first time around but on the next chef-client run when it should not delete the item which is now a link to another directory, I receive an error:

```
Errno::ENOTDIR
--------------
Not a directory @ dir_s_rmdir ...
```

Why does the guard appear to treat the link as a dir and not skip, but then the resource action recognizes it correctly, not as one, and fails? What is the best way around this?

Comment: Possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22898010/2777098

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first time, the guard checks if it's a directory. Consequent run it can check if the file directory is a symlink. Try

```
directory "#{ENV['GS_HOME']}/logs/" do
  action :delete
  only_if { ::Dir.exist?("#{ENV['GS_HOME']}/logs/") || !::File.symlink?("#{ENV['GS_HOME']}/logs/") }
end
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! Worked perfectly after removing the final slash on the File class path.